# getting a bean value in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, arraylist

i have a bean class WordBean with the following structure

```
public class WordBean 
{
    public WordList getWordList() 
    {
        return wordList;
    }
    public void setWordList(WordList wordList) 
    {
        this.wordList= wordList;
    }
}
```

WordList class with the following structure

```
public class WordList 
        {
            private List itemList = new ArrayList();

            public void setItemList(List itemList ) 
            {
               this.itemList = itemList ;
            }   

            public List getItemList() 
            {
              return itemList;
            }
         }
```

In my javascript , i need to get the retrieve the list itemList to do some validations

```
var items = document.WordBean.WordList.itemList;
```

But i am not getting any values here ?

so kindly suggest on the better syntax to retrieve the List?

Comment: Things on the server-side are not accessible from the client side - you'll need to print them to the client. You also shouldn't be doing validations on the client side.

Comment: @EvanKnowles Well, he shouldn't be doing validations *ONLY* on the client side.

Comment: Indeed. @meskobalazs's answer is what you're looking for. Just look up EL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't just use a Java variable in JavaScript! However you can print the variable in the rendering phase of JSP, and it becomes a literal from the perspective of JavaScript. So e.g. with Spring EL, you can do this:

```
var items = ${wordBean.wordList.itemList};
```

And this would render as something like this:

```
var items = ['wordOne', 'wordTwo'];
```